# docker-compose buildで構文エラー

Tags: docker-compose

お世話になっております。
下記の問題について、知見がある方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示お願いします。

## 起こっている問題

`docker-compose build`実行時、`docker-compose.yml`にて構文エラーが発生しました。
字下げなどを確認しているのですが、わかりません。

```
$ docker-compose build
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 16, column 1
could not find expected ':'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 17, column 5
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/rails/Dockerfile
    command: bundle exec unicorn_rails -c /coffee_app/config/unicorn.conf.rb
  # command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - tmp_data:/coffee_app/tmp/sockets
      - .:/coffee_app
    depends_on:
      - db
​
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/mysql/Dockerfile
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - tmp_data:/var/tmp/
​
volumes:
  db_data:
  tmp_data:
```

## 環境

ruby 2.5.1
rails 5.1.6
docker version 19.03.6
docker-compose version 1.24.0

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。

slackに記載してあるコードをコピペしていたため、16行目と34行目の空白に文字が入っていたみたいです。（slackの仕様でしょうか。。）
一度行を削除して、再度改行したら直りました。